# How to smooth out pixelated meshes

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, bevel, smooth

I downloaded a detailed terrain mesh from online. The interior of the mesh looks great, but the outer edge of the model has this rough pixelated look. Now I could try beveling each edge multiple times until it looks better, but I'm wondering if there's a faster solution that can produce a smoother shore line.

[image: Pixelated Coastline]

Comment: I don't know of a fast way to do that. You may have to do it manually.

Comment: Maybe the "Smooth Corrective" modifier could help?

Answer (score 1):

You could smooth the vertices using *Vertex > Smooth Vertices*
Choose an axis to use, in your case *x* and *y*.

[image]

Comment: This seems to get the desired result. Now I just need to figure out how to select all the vertices on the outer edge.